# Can I use <br> tag in markdown?

Tags: markdown

Can I use `<br>` tag in markdown?

> I want to separate two paragraphs.

Answer (score 9):

> When you do want to insert a <br /> break tag using Markdown, you end a line with two or more spaces, then type return.

Source: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p

Comment: 2 extra space at end of line works, but seems not a good idea as most of the text editor will auto-remove space at end of each line

Answer (score 3):

To render a break tag, from the [documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p):

> A paragraph is simply one or more consecutive lines of text, separated
>   by one or more blank lines. (A blank line is any line that looks like
>   a blank line — a line containing nothing but spaces or tabs is
>   considered blank.) Normal paragraphs should not be indented with
>   spaces or tabs.
>
> The implication of the “one or more consecutive lines of text” rule is
>   that Markdown supports “hard-wrapped” text paragraphs. This differs
>   significantly from most other text-to-HTML formatters (including
>   Movable Type’s “Convert Line Breaks” option) which translate every
>   line break character in a paragraph into a `<br />` tag.
>
> **When you do want to insert a `<br />` break tag using Markdown, you end
>   a line with two or more spaces, then type return.**
>
> Yes, this takes a tad more effort to create a `<br />`, but a simplistic
>   “every line break is a `<br />`” rule wouldn’t work for Markdown.
>   Markdown’s email-style blockquoting and multi-paragraph list items
>   work best — and look better — when you format them with hard breaks.

However, you should separate paragraphs with their `<p></p><p></p>` tags, which allow the user agent to render them correctly.

Adding a `<br />`, like this `<p></p><br /><p></p>` you'll have an "extra" break between the tags.

By the way, *this is not possible with markdown* as any blank line will automatically be converted into a paragraph.

However, if you want it inside an existing paragraph, then you have to type some text (it cannot be a blank), then end it with two or more spaces.